# I am getting an "Unhandled 'error' event" while running gulp event.js:136

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I get an error when I want to compile with gulp

`events js: 136`

I tried several modifications by recovering a node_module folder that works

I can't find a solution. Could you help me?

```js
(function() {
    var childProcess = require("child_process");
    var oldSpawn = childProcess.spawn;
    function mySpawn() {
        console.log('spawn called');
        console.log(arguments);
        var result = oldSpawn.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
    }
    childProcess.spawn = mySpawn;
})();

edit : after typing the command sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass here is what is displayed
```

```css
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin16 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.$
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

```html
throw er; // Unhandled "error" event
      ^
    Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/compass ENOENT
        at _errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
        (internal/child_process.js:201:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:389:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
I've been trying to chart the course :
```

here is the content of the log file!!!
`package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin16 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include conftest.c -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -L. -L /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.Internal.sdk/usr/local/libressl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -lruby.2.3.0 -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found

## include "ruby/config.h"

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5: return 0;
6: }`
/* end */

I'll check the compass doc to see if it's coming from there!
thank you in advance for your help.
so I tried to install compass with the command:

gem update --system
and here is the answer:

> `Updating rubygems-update
>   Fetching: rubygems-update-2.7.8.gem (100%)
>   ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>   You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.`
>   I still tried the other order to see!
>   Code :
>   gem install compass :
>   `Fetching: ffi-1.9.25.gem (100%)
>   ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>   You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.`

so I tried several things here:

> xcode-select --install
>   xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2347.

> `gem environment
>   RubyGems Environment:
>   - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.8
>   - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
>   - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
>   - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/toto/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
>   - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
>   - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
>   - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/toto/.gem/specs
>   - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
>   - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>   - ruby
>   - universal-darwin-16
>   - GEM PATHS:
>   - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
>   - /Users/toto/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
>   - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
>   - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>   - REMOTE SOURCES:
>   - https://rubygems.org/
>   - SHELL PATH:
>   - /Users/cminotti/.npm-global/bin
>   - /usr/local/bin
>   - /usr/bin
>   - /bin
>   - /usr/sbin
>   - /sbin`
>   I tried brew install ruby:
>
> `Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
>   ==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2p.tar.gz
>   Already downloaded: /Users/cminotti/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6d2f0aa30538560efe2aae756229a9ced40e636a70083696fb1bceb6c1a7564c--openssl-1.0.2p.tar.gz
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in`write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in `puts'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in`rescue in block (3 levels) in safe_fork'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in safe_fork'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:30:in`fork'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in safe_fork'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:27:in`open'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:27:in `block in safe_fork'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in`mktmpdir'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:26:in `safe_fork'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:719:in`build'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:311:in `install'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:572:in`install_dependency'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:534:in `block in install_dependencies'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:534:in`each'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:534:in `install_dependencies'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:251:in`install'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:321:in `install_formula'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:253:in`block in install'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:251:in `each'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:251:in`install'
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:89:in `<main>'
>   Error: An exception occured within a build process:
>   Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p`

I continued my research, that's what I did:
brew update :

> `touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
>   error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 527: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/UPDATE_FAILED: Permission denied
>   touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
>   error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 527: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/UPDATE_FAILED: Permission denied
>   touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-php/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
>   error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 527: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/UPDATE_FAILED: Permission denied
>   fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
>   fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
>   Cannot save the current index state
>   Error: Could not 'git stash' in /usr/local/Homebrew!
>   Please stash/commit manually if you need to keep your changes or, if not, run:
>   cd /usr/local/Homebrew
>   git reset --hard origin/master
>   cd /usr/local/Homebrew
>   git reset --hard origin/master
>   fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied`

Anyway, I'm a little stuck if anyone has an idea, I'm a taker!

Answer (score 0):

Is compass installed at that path? Please try with that.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

Comment: I used your order well here are the ones that came out

Comment: I have used your order well here are those who do :   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"

Comment: this seems like a ruby install problem. I cannot help you with that I'm sorry. Maybe ask another question?